# How to get x,y coordinates of an imageview on different devices and densities in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-touch-event

I am new with this so.. if I have an imageview on different devices 10' tablet 7' tablet and a mobile of 5' with different densities.

How I am going to get the corresponding x,y with a touch event what are the "rules" here?

thank you

The image is for example a flower when touching a petal of the flower on the imageview the position of x,y are the same in all densities and sizes?

Comment: what `x,y coordinates` do you mean?

Comment: The image is for example a flower when touching a petal of the flower on the imageview the position of x,y are the same in all densities and sizes?

Comment: so use `ImageView#getImageMatrix()` method, then use `Matrix#invert` to get inverted `Matrix` which can be used to map your touch points

Comment: any similar example?

Comment: of ImageView#getImageMatrix() method

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the width and height of `ImageView`, that is what changes in different densities. And then ask for percentages of the image, ie, for example, the half up or the fourth part down. (75% of 1024 is 1024*0.75)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int maxX = v.getWidth();
    int maxY = v.getHeight();

    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (x > (maxX * 0.25) && x < (maxX * 0.50) && y > (maxY * 0.25) && y < (maxY * 0.50)) {
            Log.i("Tag", "You pressed an area");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can easily get coordinate of a view from touch point by using touch listener methid like this,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           Log.d("Tag", "X,Y : " + event.getX() + "," + event.getY());
           return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: regardless density or screen size?

Comment: based on screen resolution it will return touch point co-ordinate. so size and density doesn't matter.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like you describe. I tried it with my Samsung Tab A tablet and my Oppo phone and got two totally different coordinates.